# Blender is seriously broken for me all of a sudden? What is going on?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders

So I haven't used Blender too much in about a week or so. I decided to open up some of the last things I was working on and was horrified at what I saw. At first, it was hard to tell what was going on exactly, and I still don't know what is happening, but it looks like some severe rendering bug related to shaders.

I can't even really describe in words what is happening because it's so weird. But basically, when I go into Material Preview or Rendered View, my mesh goes completely broken and gets some weird, warped, transparent property. I've recorded a video with a new file.

[Video of bug](https://streamable.com/ffpb0b)

I think this might be related to my updating my video card driver a couple days ago. I would revert, but the reason I updated it because otherwise Steam wouldn't launch. Has anyone else seen anything like this before? I've reinstalled already. Is this some severe bug or am I being really stupid here?

Comment: You are correct - It's caused by the latest drivers for your AMD GPU. The latest Adrenalin drivers are causing problems for many users. Roll back to an earlier driver version to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I was kinda hoping it was related to this and not some severe fudge up on my part. It's still annoying though